# Required maven dependencies for Apache POI to work

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi

I want to use Apache POI library to parse excel files (old versions and newer versions of excel). So I was wondering what jars do i need to include from the Apache POI because in following link:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi

I found lots of jars to be included, do I need to include them all?

If so, what is the latest stable version to be included, and does it work with Microsoft's Office 2010?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

No, **you** don't have to include all of *POI*'s dependencies.  Maven's transitive dependency mechanism will take care of that.  As [noted](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/3.8-beta4) you just have to express a dependency on the appropriate POI artifact.  For example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.8-beta4</version>
</dependency>
```

**Edit(UPDATE):** I don't know about previous versions but to resolve imports to XSSFWorkbook and other classes in org.apache.poi package you need to add dependency for poi-ooxml too. The dependencies will be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This won't resolve `org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader, org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable, org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage` imports.

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana I'm sorry.  I've been far removed from this space for several years now.  Please update the answer with the required edits.

Answer (score 9):

For an excel writer you might need the following:

```
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
              <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
              <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
           </dependency>


        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
       </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

this is the list of maven artifact id for all poi component.
in this link http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: The same version of "poi" and "poi-ooxml" should be used

Answer (score 2):

I used the below dependency. If you are using Selenium then it's good to use all of them as below.
Else you will see some errors and then do the reserch and add some more dependencies.

```
<dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                 <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                 <version>3.9</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                 <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                 <version>3.9</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                 <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
                 <version>3.9</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                 <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
                 <version>3.9</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                 <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
                 <version>1.1</version>
          </dependency>

          <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                 <artifactId>openxml4j</artifactId>
                 <version>1.0-beta</version>
          </dependency>
```

Comment: Apache POI 3.9 is rather old, why are you suggesting people use that? And the `openxml4j` dependency shouldn't be needed these days

Comment: can't make maven in eclipse recognize any version superior that 3.9. usually it get the job done. Also it's ridiculous to add 6-7 dependencies for something that was supposed to resolve all the dependencies for a library

Answer (score 2):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Why are you suggesting an old version? Surely 3.11, the latest stable version, would be better?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple jars which are required for your **APACHE POI** to work with your application.

*List of JAR file:-*

1. poi-4.1.0
2. poi-ooxml-4.1.0
3. commons-collections4-4.3
4. commons-compress-1.18
5. xmlbeans-3.1.0
6. poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9
7. dom4j-1.6.1

Answer (score 1):

Apache POI has mainly two libraries,

1. To process Excel '97-2007 file format (.xls), called HSSF workbook.
2. To process Excel 2007 OOXML (.xlsx), called XSSF workbook.

You can add anyone depend on your need. Difference can be found [here](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/index.html).

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using maven, then you will need **

- **poi**
- **poi-ooxml**
- **xmlbeans**
- **dom4j**
- **poi-ooxml-schemas**
- **stax-api**
- **ooxml-schemas**

Comment: The stax-api jar and dom4j jar are not needed on the latest release of Apache POI (3.11), so this is not always correct

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency to work with Apache POI

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.16-beta1</version>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

To read an Excel file with Apache POI 5.0.0 like this:

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(myFile);
```

... the following libraries are required (latest versions as I'm typing this):

- commons-collections4-4.4.jar ([link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/))
- commons-compress-1.20.jar ([link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/))
- log4j-api-2.14.1.jar ([link](https://logging.apache.org/log4j))
- log4j-core-2.14.1.jar (downloaded with ^)
- poi-5.0.0.jar ([link](https://poi.apache.org/))
- poi-ooxml-5.0.0.jar (downloaded with ^)
- poi-ooxml-lite-5.0.0.jar / poi-ooxml-full-5.0.0.jar (use only one, downloaded with ^)
- xmlbeans-5.0.0.jar ([link](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/))

If `myFile` is a ".xls" file, one more library has to be added:

- commons-math3-3.6.1.jar ([link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/))

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.5.5
 

com.dolphin
excel
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
excel
Excel Sheet Import Into Databse Using SpringBoot And Apache Worbook

<java.version>1.8</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
          <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
          <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
       </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The Main Code For Apache POI Then Update Update Maven Project

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
          <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
          <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
</dependency>
```

This Will Work

Answer (score 0):

Since POI 5.0.0, some housekeeping has been done:

According to [the official FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025):

- `poi-ooxml-full` was previously known as `ooxml-schemas`
- `poi-ooxml-lite` was previously known as `poi-ooxml-schemas`

According to [the official components list](https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components):

- `poi-ooxml` now transparently requires `poi-ooxml-lite`

As @mustafa918 noticed, you should refer to https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components to find out which dependency you need. To work with XLS, `poi` will be enough; for XLSX you will need to add `poi-ooxml`

Answer (score -2):

ooxml for dealing the .xlsx files and the ooxml refers to the xml, hence we will be needed to refer the below three dependedncies in the pom.xml for the

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
   <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
   <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.01</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
   <version>3.9</version>
   <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
       <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
       <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
     </exclusion>       
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -2):

Add these dependencies to your maven pom.xml . It will take care of all of the imports including OPCpackage

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```