# Java POI the supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML

Tags: java, excel, maven, apache-poi, xssf

I am getting this error:

> org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (e.g. XSSF instead of HSSF)

I read throw Google and I found out that I need to use XSSF instead of HSSF because my Excel file is xlsx, but as you see in my maven, I am already using xlsx. Where have I gone wrong please?

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.13-beta1</version>
    </dependency>
```

The code the makes the exception is:

```
POIFSFileSystem fs;

            fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(getFilePath()));
```

#### My new code

```
public void getBColum() {
    try {
        OPCPackage fs;

        fs = new OPCPackage.open(new File(getFilePath()));

        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Master column name - Used Car");
        XSSFRow row;
        CellReference cr = new CellReference("A1");
        row = sheet.getRow(cr.getCol());
        System.out.println(row.getCell(3));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("How can this error be possible? we should have already thrown an exception in the construction");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(String.format("Exception in reading the file: %s",
                e.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

I have a compile error in `new oPCPackage.open` which is:

> OPCPackage.open cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Please show the relevant code that threw the exception.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

According to the [Apache POI Quick Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream), the `POIFSFileSystem` (or similarly, `NPOIFSFileSystem`) is only used with .xls (Excel versions through 2003) documents.

The equivalent for .xlsx documents (Excel 2007+) is `OPCPackage`.

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new File("file.xlsx"));
```

You can create an `XSSFWorkbook` from the `OPCPackage`:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
```

Or you can just create it directly:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new File("file.xlsx"));
```

Generally it's better to create the workbook using a `File` instead of an `InputStream`, to save memory.

Also, if you want code that doesn't care whether it's an .xls or an .xlsx:

```
// or "file.xlsx"
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("MyExcel.xls"));
```

Comment: there is wrong in the first line `opcpackage.open`  .... `OPCPackage.open cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: `import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;`

Comment: that is what i am importing, and i am having the error

Comment: It works for me, when I catch the `InvalidFormatException` that `open` throws.

Comment: maybe your forgot something in your code here, because, as you see in the updated question, i am having a compiler error, i am using java 8

Comment: Now that I see your code, remove the "new" -- `OPCPackage.open` is a `static` method.  Try `fs = OPCPackage.open(new File(getFilePath()));`.

Comment: import this dependence to your project:    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.8-beta4:'
 or check here if like me, you were missing dependences to use XSSF objects https://stackoverflow.com/a/8202181/7953908

Answer (score 4):

I was using XSSF with a xlsx file, but got this error when I tried to process a file that was encrypted/protected with a password.

Once I removed the password, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

well actually there is no OPCPackage,
I am using https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/3.5-beta5
so you have to:

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package;
....
Package fs = Package.open(new ByteArrayInputStream(container.getContent()));
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            XSSFRow row;
            XSSFCell cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used .xlsx file in Appian and it got resolved.
#appian