# How to open password protected docx file in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi, docx

I want to open a password protected docx file using Apache POI. Can anyone help me with the complete code please? Am not getting solution with this code

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.(HeaderBlock.java:126)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.(HeaderBlock.java:113)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:301)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:413)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:394)

```
  POIFSFileSystem fs=new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream("D:/abc.docx"));
    EncryptionInfo info=new EncryptionInfo(fs);
    Decryptor decryptor=Decryptor.getInstance(info);
    if(!decryptor.verifyPassword("user"))
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("document is encrypted");
    }
    InputStream in=decryptor.getDataStream(fs);
    HSSFWorkbook wb=new HSSFWorkbook(in);
    File f=new File("D:/abc5.docx");
    wb.write(f);
```

Comment: please tell what you got and what not. by code level i should work

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException:

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: HSSFWorkbook wb=new HSSFWorkbook(in);

Comment: please give full stack trace

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844308/java-poi-the-supplied-data-appears-to-be-in-the-office-2007-xml

Comment: instead of this POIFSFileSystem fs;
            fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(getFilePath())); use this new OPCPackage.open(new FileInputStream(getFilePath()))

Comment: edited please check....this is the whole error am getting

Comment: use XSSFWorkbook instead of HSSFWorkbook

Comment: EncryptionInfo(OPCPackage) is not supported

Comment: can you please give me full code if you have.

Answer (score 2):

The basic code for decryption the XML-based formats of Microsoft Office is shown in [XML-based formats - Decryption](https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html#XML-based+formats+-+Decryption).

But of course one must know that `*.docx`, which is a `Word` file in Office Open XML format,  cannot be a `HSSFWorkbook`, which would be a `Excel` workbook in binary `BIFF` file format, but instead must be a `XWPFDocument`.

So:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor;

import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.Decryptor;

import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;

public class ReadEncryptedXWPF {

 static XWPFDocument decryptdocx(POIFSFileSystem filesystem, String password) throws Exception {

  EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(filesystem);
  Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);

  try {
   if (!d.verifyPassword(password)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to process: document is encrypted");
   }

   InputStream dataStream = d.getDataStream(filesystem);

   return new XWPFDocument(dataStream);

  } catch (GeneralSecurityException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to process encrypted document", ex);
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  POIFSFileSystem filesystem = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream("abc.docx"));
  XWPFDocument document = decryptdocx(filesystem, "user");

  XWPFWordExtractor extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(document);
  System.out.println(extractor.getText());
  extractor.close();

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this. The code is below

```
    POIFSFileSystem fs=new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream("D:/abc.docx"));
    EncryptionInfo info=new EncryptionInfo(fs);
    Decryptor decryptor=Decryptor.getInstance(info);
    XWPFDocument document=null;
    if(decryptor.verifyPassword("password"))
    {
          InputStream dataStream = decryptor.getDataStream(fs); 
          document = new XWPFDocument(dataStream); 
    }else{
        throw new Exception("file is protected with password...please open with right password");
    }
    File f=new File("D:/abc.docx");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    document.write(fos);
    document.close();
```