# Error: Unable to initialize main class newpackage.MyClass Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row

Tags: apache-poi

```
package newpackage;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
 
//How to read excel files using Apache POI
public class MyClass {
public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException{
                        //I have placed an excel file 'Test.xlsx' in my D Driver
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("filepath\\DemoFile.xlsx");
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                        //I have added test data in the cell A1 as "SoftwareTestingMaterial.com"
                        //Cell A1 = row 0 and column 0. It reads first row as 0 and Column A as 0.
Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
                       System.out.println(cell);
System.out.println(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0));
//String cellval = cell.getStringCellValue();
//System.out.println(cellval);
fis.close();
}
}
```

getting below error
Error: Unable to initialize main class newpackage.MyClass
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row

i have added all jar files
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQu9z.png)

Comment: Are you sure `poi-bin-4.1.2-20200217` is a `jar` file? I suspect it is a `*.zip`  file and classloader will not get `jar`s from inside a `zip`.

Comment: zip file has jar files , i have added all jars which are present and including  Lib and ooxml-lib

Comment: The error tells it lacks `poi-4.1.2.jar` in class path.

Answer (score 1):

Create a maven project and add below dependencies to get all required jars for POI to work fine.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.8-beta4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Refer to the answer here
[Required maven dependencies for Apache POI to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202008/required-maven-dependencies-for-apache-poi-to-work)