# Getting exception while using XSSFWorkbook - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, automation, dependencies, testng, rest-assured

While using XSSFWorkbook getting below exception, added org.apache.poi dependancy

my code is as below, it prints **projDir** and throws exception after that as mentioned below

```
public class ExcelUtils {
    public static void main(String []args){
            getRowCount();
        }
        public static void getRowCount(){
            try {
            String projDir =System.getProperty("user.dir");
            System.out.println(projDir);
            String excelPath = "./data/TestData.xlsx";
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelPath);
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            System.out.println(exp.getMessage());
            System.out.println(exp.getCause());
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
```

And below is full log track

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:149)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.<init>(OPCPackage.java:136)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.<init>(Package.java:54)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:98)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:199)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:178)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.openPackage(POIXMLDocument.java:62)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:188)
    at utils.ExcelUtils.getRowCount(ExcelUtils.java:24)
    at utils.ExcelUtils.main(ExcelUtils.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Is this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202008/required-maven-dependencies-for-apache-poi-to-work helpful?

Comment: No, I already have added those mentioned dependancies in pom.xml

Comment: Then maybe just add the dependency to dom4J in whata build system/IDE you're using?

Comment: Added that too but still not working. I am using Eclipse. And i am able to do test for other  classes of same project